# free-Jqgrid expand /collapse grid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

How expand/collapse the grid simply by clicking on the title bar,not on the small button on the right corner?
[Example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideOnClick1.htm)

working

```
  $("#idButton").click(function () {
  $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close", myGrid[0].grid.cDiv).click();
});
```

does not work

```
$(myGrid[0].grid.cDiv).click(function() {
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close",this).click();
 });
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83dp23uu/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just move the code

```js
var myGrid = $("#list"), titleDiv = myGrid[0].grid.cDiv;

$("#idButton").click(function () {
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close", titleDiv).click();
});

$(titleDiv).click(function() {
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close",this).click();
});
```

**inside of** `$(function () {/*here*/})`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/83dp23uu/9/. Your original demo try to bind `click` event to element, which is not yet created.